# Connecting predefined HTML to Models and Views in Backbone

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm starting out with Backbone.js so I must say I'm not yet very familiar with the concepts.

I have predefined HTML and I want to use Backbone to manage this. This is important and I want to keep it like this.

Say this is (part of) my HTML:

```
<div class="pig" data-id="1">
    <h1>Harry</h1>
    <input type="text" value="Harry">
</div>
<div class="pig" data-id="2">
    <h1>Jill</h1>
    <input type="text" value="Jill">
</div>
<div class="pig" data-id="3">
    <h1>Bob</h1>
    <input type="text" value="Bob">
</div>
```

Now the idea is that when you change the input this should update my Backbone Model and render the view, resuling in the `h1` being updated with the new name. I'm not sure how I should set up my models and views.

I kind of have the structure of my models and my views, but I don't know how I should use them.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
var PigModel = Backbone.Model.extend()
var pigs = new PigModel()
pigs.reset([
    {"id": "1", "name": "Harry"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Jill"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "Bob"}
])

var PigView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.pig',
    events: {
        'change input': function() {
            // update appropriate Model ?
            this.render()
        }
    },
    render: function() {

        var new_name = // get new name from model ?

        var pig_template = _.template($('#pig_template').html())
        var new_contents = pig_template({ name: new_name })

        // render only the pig that was changed ?

    }
})
```

So at the places where I added comments in the code I don't know what to do:

- At the `change` event, how do I find the model that belongs to this view? I could loop through all the models but that seems inefficient.
- Again in the render method, how do I get the model that belongs to this view?
- In the render method, how can I only render the pig view the event was on, and not render all the pigs?

Maybe I'm going for a total wrong approach over here. If so, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Backbone doesn't work like this. You could hack it with a load of code  in the view's `initialize` function but really you need to be rendering the HTML in the view, not using pre-rendered HTML. The whole point of Backbone is to _separate_ the display of the model and the model itself

Comment: @Bojangles I actually found out a pretty clean way to do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure it out.

The idea is to loop through your existing HTML using jQuery, then creating instances of views and models of it using the jquery selectors and the preloaded json.

HTML:

```
<div class="pig">
    <h1>Harry</h1>
    <input type="text" value="Harry" />
</div>
<div class="pig">
    <h1>Jill</h1>
    <input type="text" value="Jill" />
</div>
<div class="pig">
    <h1>Bob</h1>
    <input type="text" value="Bob" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    var PigModel = Backbone.Model.extend()

    var PigView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'change input': function(e) {
                this.model.set('name', e.currentTarget.value)
                this.render()
            }
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(
                '<h1>' + this.model.get('name') + '</h1>' +
                '<input type="text" value="' + this.model.get('name') + '" />'
            )
        }
    })

    var pig_data = [
        {"name": "Harry"},
        {"name": "Jill"},
        {"name": "Bob"}
    ]


    // the magic starts here

    var pig_number = 0

    $('.pig').each(function() {

        new PigView({
            el: this,
            model: new PigModel(pig_data[pig_number])
        })

    })

})
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tU3Mt/1/

Like this I can serve a complete HTML page from the server, then load the desired elements into my backbone views/models and manage them from there.

About wether this is the way backbone should be used or not:
It may not be the most logical/efficient way to do this from a developer point of view. However, I think this approach has some important benefits:

- The client get's HTML served directly and won't have to process any javascript before the page can be presented. This will become more noticable as your HTML gets bigger/more complex.
- Search engines/web crawlers can read your page because it serves the complete HTML.

For some people these points may not be that important, because a webapp will be fast after it has been loaded and search engines won't have to crawl it. However in some situations you might have a mix of a website and a webapp, where the page needs to load fast, be crawlable but also have a responsive interface which is complex enough to make a developer want to use something like backbone. If somebody has other ideas about this I sure like to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a little bit of a different approach. Create a collection of `Pig` models. Have a view that knows how to render a single pig, `PigView`. Let it be responsible for updating the one pig and it's corresponding `h1`. Have a higher level view that renders the collection of pigs into whatever parent element you want.

```
var PigModel = Backbone.Model.extend()
// You want a collection of pig models
var pigs = new Backbone.Collection([
    {"id": "1", "name": "Harry"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Jill"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "Bob"}
], {model: PigModel});

var PigView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Want to set the class for the generated el not pass a selector
    className : "pig",
    // Dummy template from your markup in question
    template : function (modelAttrs) {
        return "<h1>"+modelAttrs.name+"</h1><input type='text' value='"+modelAttrs.name+"'>";
    },
    events: {
        'change input': function(e) {
            // You have a reference to the model through this
            this.model.set({name : e.currentTarget.value});
            this.render();
        }
    },
    // Bare bones render
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});

// Parent view for responsible for rendering the collection of pigs somewhere.
var HigherLevelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render : function () {
        pigs.each(function (pig) {
            this.$el.append(new PigView({model : pig}).render().el);
        });
    }
});

$("body").append(new HigherLevelView().render().el);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vc49s/)

Comment: Ok, I understand your approach, but I have existing HTML that I want to hook my Backbone views to. So I don't want Backbone to have to render anything the first time my page loads. The first time my page loads the HTML is already rendered server-side. Then when the client side loads, I want to start altering my DOM with Backbone on certain events.

Answer (score 0):

Attach to existing html is possible, but it is not very common approach. Because of that, there is almost no real info on this :(

You could try to follow steps described in following article: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/

Idea is, to add some data-attribute into rendered html, so you will be able to match model with rendered html.

Comment: I actually found out a pretty clean way to do what I wanted. See my answer.