# Selected option not visible using Backbone.js in windows phone 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-phone-7, backbone.js

Am using `Backbone.js` file to retrieve the data from back end and display it on the HTML. Here i can retrieve the values correctly but cannot able to show the retrieved value in the select option. What am missing here?

**HTML**

```
<select class="custom-select" name="number-of-sets" id="number-of-sets">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>  
   <option>3</option>  
   <option>4</option> 
   <option>5</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
 var c = window.setInterval(function() {
      clearInterval(c);
      $("#number-of-sets").find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
      $("#number-of-sets option").each(function() {
             $(this).prop("selected",false);
             if(2==$(this).val())    //say i retrieved value '2' and i got it true
               { 
                 alert("check");
                 $(this).prop("selected",true); 
                 alert("no of seats::"+$(this).val()+";"+$(this).prop("selected")); 
                 return false;  
               } 
          }); 
        }, 500); 
      this.render();
    },
```

Comment: I believe that "this" in this.render() is referring to the scope of the function and not your view...console.log(this) or console.debug(this) to see?

Comment: @redconservatory Yes, It tends to scope of the function.

Comment: Then aren't you calling render on the function instead of the view - 
I mean, aren't you trying to call render on the view so you can see it?

Comment: @redconservatory, Am sorry not sure about what way you mean as backbone.js is new to me. Could you please elaborate it in detail?

Comment: render is a function of a Backbone View object...it tells the view how to render itself (i.e. render a template or make some html) but the way you have it written here you are calling "render" on the function inside of setInterval which you have not written.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting predefined HTML to Models and Views in Backbone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687972/connecting-predefined-html-to-models-and-views-in-backbone)